# Local variable 'Veh_C2X_attributes' referenced before assignment Source?

Tags: python, variables

I tried to run this script from a microsimulation software PTV VISSIM. and getting this error. Local variable 'Veh_C2X_attributes' referenced before assignment  Source?? in my script i have created a list named 'Veh_C2X_attributes' using a list comprehension. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Script.

```
def Init():
    #Global Parameters
    global distDistr
    global Vehicle_Type_C2X_no_message
    global Vehicle_Type_C2X_HasCurrentMessage
    Veh_attributes = None

    distDistr = 1 # number of Distance distribution used for sending out a C2X message
    Vehicle_Type_C2X_no_message = '101' # number of C2X vehicle type (no active message) has to be a string!
    Vehicle_Type_C2X_HasCurrentMessage = '102' # number of C2X vehicle type with active message has to be a string!
    return



def Main():
    # Get several attributes of all vehicles:
    Veh_attributes = Vissim.Net.Vehicles.GetMultipleAttributes(('Pos', 'VehType', 'No'))
    if len(Veh_attributes) > 0: # Check if there are any vehicles in the network:
       # Filter by VehType C2X:
        Veh_C2X_attributes = None
        Veh_C2X_attributes = [item for item in Veh_attributes if item[1] == Vehicle_Type_C2X_no_message or item[1] == Vehicle_Type_C2X_HasCurrentMessage]    #Getting Error here
#Check if the Vehicle is in the range
    for C2X_Veh in range(len(Veh_C2X_attributes)):
        if Veh_C2X_attributes[C2X_Veh][0]==300:
            Veh_sending_Msg = Vissim.Net.Vehicles.ItemByKey(Veh_C2X_attributes[C2X_Veh][3])
            Coord_Veh = Veh_sending_Msg.AttValue('CoordFront') # reading the world coordinates (x y z) of the vehicle
            PositionXYZ = Coord_Veh.split(" ")
            Pos_Veh_SM = Veh_sending_Msg.AttValue('Pos') # relative position on the current link
            Veh_sending_Msg.SetAttValue('C2X_HasCurrentMessage', 1)
            Veh_sending_Msg.SetAttValue('C2X_SendingMessage', 1)
            Veh_sending_Msg.SetAttValue('C2X_MessageOrigin', Pos_Veh_SM)
            # Getting vehicles which receive the message:
            Veh_Rec_Message = Vissim.Net.Vehicles.GetByLocation(PositionXYZ[0], PositionXYZ[1], distDistr)
    return
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well your `if len(Veh_attributes) > 0:` fails and hence `Veh_C2X_attributes` is not defined.

One way to make it sure is by putting a `print` in `if len(Veh_attributes) > 0:` to check if that condition is being executed.

Also a better practice would be to define `Veh_C2X_attributes` before.

eg:

```
def Main():
    # Get several attributes of all vehicles:
    Veh_C2X_attributes = [] # this will prevent code from failing
    Veh_attributes = Vissim.Net.Vehicles.GetMultipleAttributes(('Pos', 'VehType', 'No'))
    if len(Veh_attributes) > 0: # Check if there are any vehicles in the network:
       # Filter by VehType C2X:
        Veh_C2X_attributes = [item for item in Veh_attributes if item[1] == Vehicle_Type_C2X_no_message or item[1] == Vehicle_Type_C2X_HasCurrentMessage]    #Getting Error here
#Check if the Vehicle is in the range
    for C2X_Veh in range(len(Veh_C2X_attributes)):
        if Veh_C2X_attributes[C2X_Veh][0]==300:
            Veh_sending_Msg = Vissim.Net.Vehicles.ItemByKey(Veh_C2X_attributes[C2X_Veh][3])
            Coord_Veh = Veh_sending_Msg.AttValue('CoordFront') # reading the world coordinates (x y z) of the vehicle
            PositionXYZ = Coord_Veh.split(" ")
            Pos_Veh_SM = Veh_sending_Msg.AttValue('Pos') # relative position on the current link
            Veh_sending_Msg.SetAttValue('C2X_HasCurrentMessage', 1)
            Veh_sending_Msg.SetAttValue('C2X_SendingMessage', 1)
            Veh_sending_Msg.SetAttValue('C2X_MessageOrigin', Pos_Veh_SM)
            # Getting vehicles which receive the message:
            Veh_Rec_Message = Vissim.Net.Vehicles.GetByLocation(PositionXYZ[0], PositionXYZ[1], distDistr)
    return
```

Comment: I would remove/edit this answer if someone could convince me why it was down voted.